# Bash command return only search pattern from the line

Tags: bash, design-patterns, sed, matching, linux-mint

I' ve got a `.sql` file that contains mysql commands and I want to retrieve from the file, the part that refers to `CREATE TABLE` commands.

I have tried the following command:

```
sed -n '/CREATE TABLE/ , /ENGINE=InnoDB/p' my file > dbTables
```

which looks for "statements" that start from `CREATE TABLE` and finish to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Lets suppose that the `CREATE TABLE` statement finishes with `EGINE=InnoDB` string.

The problem is that the file, in some cases, keeps at the same line that both `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements.

So, the above command returns the entire line.

How can the `sed` command return only the pattern and not the entire line?

Comment: What do you want to match? We need a better example of input and output.

Comment: You can use grep with the -wo flags to match just the specific content, not sure about sed but a google search throws lots of stuff up so I don't know why this post was needed